# Is OSM route plugin working?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, isochrone

I have computed some isochrones using OSM route plugin but when I am trying to use the plugin again it gives me an error: An error has occured while executing Python code.

Is it working for you?

Comment: A more detailed description and the python traceback would be helpful.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Somebody/.qgis2/python/plugins\OSMroute\OSMroute.py", line 244, in run
    numberOfHits_start = child.attrib["numberOfGeocodedAddresses"]
KeyError: 'numberOfGeocodedAddresses'

Comment: Running in 2.14.0 on Mac OSX I get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_name/.qgis2/python/plugins/OSMroute/OSMroute.py", line 245, in run
    if numberOfHits_start != "0":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numberOfHits_start' referenced before assignment``` which suggests a similar cause as numberOfHits_start is the trigger for the error in both. I've tried copying the start and target addresses from the website's own geocoding but with no luck.

Comment: As far as I know, it only works in Europe, are you trying to use it somewhere else?

Comment: I have tried for an address in Denmark from where I have already been able to compute isochrones before. I guess that it was just a temporary issue in the software because now it is back on track.

Answer (score 2):

OSMroute plugin does not work since OpenRouteService API has been [changed](http://k1z.blog.uni-heidelberg.de/2017/04/29/openrouteservice-with-new-api-functions-and-look/). Furthermore, the author of OSMroute plugin explained in his [blog post](http://www.digital-geography.com/short-announcement-new-osm-routing-plugin-for-qgis-osm-tools/#.WTK0zMYlGUk) that he decided to stop further development of the plugin. In the blog  post, you can find information about another [alternative](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMtools/) for computing isochrones in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the plugin I played with the call to the geocoding server and discovered that it really is very sensitive to the address format. I got sensible results in Sweden only when using city names. Streets just didnt work

Comment: If you look at the Python code it sends a request to a server for geocoding but it is evidently not capable of parsing "weird" European addresses. It's not a character issue; "Gävle, Sweden" is fine but more specific addresses fail. I'll look into bypassing the geocoding bit but I'm still learning pgrouting and postgis myself, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: The server has been having problems of late which has caused both the plugin and the openrouteservice.org website to not respond or to behave oddly. But generally the geocoding is a little sensitive. The plugin is also in need of some work. I have looked at it and started on an improvement; as it is now it takes an address and converts that to WGS84 coordinates. I am working on an update that should allow you to enter WGS84 directly from the canvas. But don't wait on that to happen soon.